# Can't reconnect to Wi-Fi after disconnecting

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, dhcp, wpa-supplicant

I use Arch Linux and this is the command I usually use to disconnect from the Internet: `sudo wpa_cli -i wlp2s0 -p /var/run/wpa_supplicant\ GROUP\=wheel/ terminate`. To connect again, I use: `sudo wpa_supplicant -B -i wlp2s0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant-wlp2s0.conf`. That works at my home, but not here at my cousin's house.

I establish some kind of connection since I at least get Wi-Fi's name (`iwgetid` returns the correct name of wlan). But that's all, there is no connection with the Internet.

I even tried running `sudo dhcpcd -b` after `sudo wpa_supplicant -B -i wlp2s0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant-wlp2s0.conf` but it has no effect.

Comment: Guess: The second time you start `wpa_supplicant` it has a slightly different configuration than the first time it gets started automatically. Is there any reason you have to terminate `wpa_supplicant` to disconnect? Why not use whatever way your distro uses (network manager, ifup/ifdown, disconnect with `wpa_cli`, whatever?)

Comment: @dirkt "The second time you start wpa_supplicant it has a slightly different configuration than the first time it gets started automatically." Why do you think so? "Is there any reason you have to terminate wpa_supplicant to disconnect? Why not use whatever way your distro uses (network manager, ifup/ifdown, disconnect with wpa_cli, whatever?)" I don't have neither network manager or ifup/ifdown. As for wpa_cli, I don't think that can be done using it. PS: I'm a minimalist.

Comment: [connect/disconnect via wpa_cli](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/314381/how-to-disconnect-from-network-via-wpa-cli). Still think it can't be done?

Comment: @dirkt Doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found another, better way that does the same thing (and does it right):

**To disconnect:**

`sudo ip link set dev wlp2s0 down && sudo dhclient -r wlp2s0`

**To connect:**

`sudo ip link set dev wlp2s0 up && sudo dhclient wlp2s0`

Comment: I'm minimalistic myself, but at least I let ifup/ifdown handle DHCP ...

Comment: Maybe that's a better idea, I'll check it out. :)